# What does "Export CI=true" do in this create-react-app deploy script?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, deployment, create-react-app

There's a file called `launch.sh` in our Create React App, that is used to publish things to the CDN. One of the lines in there says `export CI=true`. I have no idea what "CI" means in this context, and what it does.

Comment: Neither do we. It sets an environment variable to "true".

Comment: Without context you will never get an answer here. CI usually means Continuous Integration , and considering the tagging, I believe it should trigger a build/test from jenkins. Yet it could also mean "Can't Imagine" the numerous possibilities it can have.

Answer (score 19):

Read the docs, as ever:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#continuous-integration

> #### Continuous Integration
>
> By default `npm test` runs the watcher with interactive CLI. However,
>   you can force it to run tests once and finish the process by setting
>   an environment variable called `CI`.
>
> When creating a build of your application with `npm run build` linter
>   warnings are not checked by default. Like `npm test`, you can force the
>   build to perform a linter warning check by setting the environment
>   variable `CI`. If any warnings are encountered then the build fails.
>
> [...]